# Is there a web interface to query Freebase RDF data using SPARQL?

Tags: freebase, mql

I know that Freebase recently uploaded their data in form of a RDF file. Is there any web interface where I can query this RDF data via a SPARQL end point?

Also, is there any web portal where I can upload this RDF file and then query it using SPARQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Google/Freebase provided SPARQL endpoint.  I've never heard of a generic RDF/SPARQL hosting service (I presume you're looking for something free).  It doesn't seem like the kind of thing that one could develop a viable business model for.

Of course, you can just spin up an Amazon EC2 instance with your favorite quad store and SPARQL front end and load the RDF dump into that if you don't have local dedicated compute resources available to you.

Comment: Hi, I tried to dump the rdf data into a JENA TDBLoader and got errors. It looks like there are errors inside the rdf dump file that need to be corrected. Is Metaweb releasing another corrected version of the rdf dump? I confirmed about the errors from the JENA users list.

Comment: Well, it'd be Google, not Metaweb, but I wouldn't presume to speak for someone else in either case.  You'll need to ask them.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Is there any email id of Google that I can contact to confirm the error in the published RDF dump please?

Comment: Its not uncommon to have errors in an RDF dump. usually it is with data types or something having to do with literals. Try to figure out what the "error" or unhandled triple type is and do a find and replace to remove them from the dump and re-run